# removing variables from Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying some deep learning experiments with various hyper parameters. I build model for each hyper parameter settings separately. After first hyperparameter setting is trained and evaluated, when I try to build a new model with second setting, it gives me an error related to variable reused and stuff.

So I want to **reset** my session after each experiment. How can I do that?

I've tried `tf.reset_default_graph()`, but when I call `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`, it gives me following error:

> ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init"
>   op: "NoOp"
>   input: "^v/Assign"
>    is not an element of this graph.)

How can I remove all variables and **reset** my session peacefully?

Comment: Session uses the graph attached to it. So even though you reset default graph, session will use the graph before the reset

Answer (score 5):

After you have reset the default graph, you will also need to create a new session. A small example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()  # Create new session
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```